# SQL Server 2012 Bulk Insert Type Mismatch Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert

I'm a beginner, just learning my way around SQL-Server and I seem to have hit wall using BULK INSERT. I've lurked across similar threads but I have two type mismatch errors I simply cannot figure out.

Here is the table (psuedo-SQL)

```
CREATE TABLE patient (
    Acct bigint primary key,
    FacNo varchar(50) not null,
    AccountKey varchar(50) not null,
    LastName varchar(50),
    FirstName varchar(50),
    MI varchar(5),
    RespName varchar(50),
    Address varchar(50),
    City varchar(50),
    State varchar(5),
    ZipCode varchar(15),
    ReasonDesc varchar(50),
    HomePhone varchar(18),
    Sex varchar(5),
    BirthDate datetime,
    SSN varchar(50),
    MaritalStat varchar(10),
    EmployedStatus varchar(5),
    Employer varchar(50),
    EmpAddr varchar(50),
    EmpCity varchar(50),
    EmpState char(15),
    EmpZip varchar(15),
    WorkPhone varchar(18),
    WorkPhoneExt varchar(5),
    RelatedToEmploy char(15),
    RelatedToAccident char(15),
    AutoState varchar(5),
    ADOS datetime,
    BDOS datetime,
    -- some fields
    PTOS decimal(10,2),
    -- and some more fields
    )
```

Here is my BULK INSERT statement

```
BULK INSERT patient
FROM patient.csv 
WITH (
  FIRSTROW = 2, 
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

And the errors returned are

> 4864, Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid
>   character for the specified codepage) for row 347, column 29
>   (ADOS)
>
> 4864, Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid
>   character for the specified codepage) for row 347, column 49 (PTOS)

At both locations where the error is thrown there are

- No extra whitespaces
- No hidden characters
- Format of the values are the same as the previous 346 similar type values.

In the data file, patient.csv all of the datetime columns are in the format MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss (ADOS is no exception) and PTOS is literally a whole column of just 0.00

So why is it only in row 347 that these throw an error?

Comment: Maybe there is a comma (or even a `new line`) somewhere within one of the `varchar` values before `ADOS`. Since that is your fieldterminator, it would explain the error.

Comment: Same conclusion as @HoneyBadger. I bet your Employer or EmpAddr has a comma in it for row 347: e.g. CompanyName, LLP